# How to install all gcloud components at once

Tags: gcloud

I would like to know how to install all of the Gcloud components at the same time.

[image]

Comment: 1) First of all, do not install everything. Some components have side effects that will affect your system. Only install the components you require. 2) The only solution I know of is to write a script that parses the component list and installs missing components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/install),

You can install the required components using `gcloud components install COMPONENT-1 COMPONENT-2`, where COMPONENT-1 COMPONENT-2 are the Id’s of the respective components.

Currently there is no gcloud command that might help you to install all the components at once, so you will have to follow the above mentioned procedure to install them as required.

If you want this feature to get added to the Google Cloud, then you can also raise a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) where the engineering team will look into it. Also remember that there is no ETA for the feature requests.

Answer (score 1):

As the Cloud SDK is constantly updated,  the ways to interact with it often change too.

The command below used to work and installed all components in one line,  I checked today and it no longer works,  however it may provide you with some insights into how to install all components in one go.

gcloud components list | grep "^| Not" | sed "s/|(.*)|(.*)|(.*)|/\2/" | xargs echo gcloud components update

Answer (score 1):

An updated command:

```
gcloud components install `gcloud components list | grep "Not Installed" | awk -F '│' '{print $4}' | xargs`
```

It achieves this by:

1. Listing all components and their statuses
2. Filtering out only those that are not installed
3. Extracting the component names/IDs
4. Passing those component names/IDs to the gcloud components
   install command for installation